# Using the Web Console, Is it possible to Change the Membase Memory Quota?

Tags: membase

Let's say I have a Membase server with a memory quota of 1GB. Is it possible to change it and make it larger, say 8GB, assuming the server gets a hardware upgrade?

Currently, I have the impression that Membase memory quota is unchangeable once set, which is very frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1.6.5 at least, you can change it from Web console. From Manage | Data Buckets, you can reset your RAM quota.

But for a cluster, it won't be that easy though because it is required to have same memory quota across all cluster nodes.